# Flutter flutter_background_service not start always when app is in killed state

Tags: flutter, flutter-workmanager

Sometime background service start if app is in killed state, but sometimes background service stop with error: Flutter engine disconnected. Connected engine count 0

**Main function**

```
void main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 await initializeService();
}
```

**Start Background Service if app in killed state**

```
 @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);\
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      print('_isInForeground');
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      print('_isInBackground');
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.detached) {
      print('_isInKilled');
      serviceBackground.startService();
    }
  }
```

**Flutter background service page**

```
Future<void> initializeService() async {
  final serviceBackground = FlutterBackgroundService();
  AndroidNotificationChannel channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
    "App",
    "foreground service",
    importance: Importance.high,
  );
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  await serviceBackground.configure(
      iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(),
      androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
        onStart: onStart,
        isForegroundMode: true,
        autoStart: true,
        notificationChannelId: "App",
        initialNotificationTitle: "foreground service",
        initialNotificationContent: "initializing",
        foregroundServiceNotificationId: 888,
      ));
  serviceBackground.startService();
}

@pragma('vm-entry-point')
Future<void> onStart(ServiceInstance serviceBackground) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  serviceBackground.on('stopService').listen((event) {
    print("stopService : $event");
    serviceBackground.stopSelf();
  });

  if (serviceBackground is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    if (await serviceBackground.isForegroundService()) {
      Geolocator.getPositionStream(
          locationSettings: const LocationSettings(
        accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
        distanceFilter: 20,
      )).listen((Position? position) {
        addItem(position?.latitude, position?.longitude);
      });

      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        888,
        "Background ON",
        "Location Tracked",
        const NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          "App",
          "foreground service",
          ongoing: true,
        )),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

I am unable to find the issue as worker starts sometimes but not always.

Comment: Can anyone please help with this issue?